# How do I use LINQ group by clause to return unique employee rows?

Tags: linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I'm pretty new to LINQ, and I can't for the life of me figure this out. I've seen lots of posts on how to use the group by in LINQ, but for some reason, I can't get it to work. This is so easy in ADO.NET, but I'm trying to use LINQ. Here's what I have that is relevant to the problem. I have marked the part that doesn't work.

```
public class JoinResult
{
    public int LocationID;
    public int EmployeeID;
    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;
    public string Position;
    public bool Active;
}
private IQueryable<JoinResult> JoinResultIQueryable;
public IList<JoinResult> JoinResultIList;

JoinResultIQueryable = (
    from e in IDDSContext.Employee
    join p in IDDSContext.Position on e.PositionID equals p.PositionID
    join el in IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation on e.EmployeeID equals el.EmployeeID
    where e.PositionID != 1 // Do not display the super administrator's data.
    orderby e.LastName, e.FirstName

// ***** Edit: I forgot to add this line of code, which applies a filter
// ***** to the IQueryable. It is this filter (or others like it that I
// ***** have omitted) that causes the query to return multiple rows.
// ***** The EmployeeLocationsList contains multiple LocationIDs, hence
// ***** the duplicates employees that I need to get rid of. 
JoinResultIQueryable = JoinResultIQueryable
    .Where(e => EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(e.LocationID);
// *****


    // ***** The following line of code is what I want to do, but it doesn't work.
    // ***** I just want the above join to bring back unique employees with all the data.
    // ***** Select Distinct is way too cumbersome, so I'm using group by.
    group el by e.EmployeeID

    select new JoinResult
    {
        LocationID = el.LocationID,
        EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
        LastName = e.LastName,
        FirstName = e.FirstName,
        Position = p.Position1,
        Active = e.Active
    })
    .AsNoTracking();

JoinResultIList = await JoinResultIQueryable
    .ToListAsync();
```

How do I get from the IQueryable to the IList only returning the unique employee rows?

***** Edit:
Here is my current output:

```
[4][4][Anderson (OH)][Amanda][Dentist][True]
[5][4][Anderson (OH)][Amanda][Dentist][True]
[4][25][Stevens (OH)][Sally][Dental Assistant][True]
[4][30][Becon (OH)][Brenda][Administrative Assistant][False]
[5][30][Becon (OH)][Brenda][Administrative Assistant][False]
```

Comment: You should use into operator when grouping using linq see i.e.  group el by e.EmployeeID into g   and then use g  is the select 

e.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a try, but it didn't work for me. :)

Comment: By your data it seems your there is one to many relationship between Location and Employee correct ?

Comment: please see my below answer

Comment: Yes. There is a one-to-many relationship between Employee and EmployeeLocation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need grouping here, but `Distinct`. Ordering before `Distinct` or grouping is useless. Also `AsNoTracking` with custom projection is not needed.

```cs
var query =
   from e in IDDSContext.Employee
   join p in IDDSContext.Position on e.PositionID equals p.PositionID
   join el in IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation on e.EmployeeID equals el.EmployeeID
   where e.PositionID != 1 // Do not display the super administrator's data.
   select new JoinResult
   {
        LocationID = el.LocationID,
        EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
        LastName = e.LastName,
        FirstName = e.FirstName,
        Position = p.Position1,
        Active = e.Active
   };

query = query.Distinct().OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ThenBy(e => e.FirstName);

JoinResultIList = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I was hopeful that this would work, but it didn't. I realize that Distinct is what I want in SQL. Thanks for the heads up about AsNoTracking().

Comment: This did not work for me: query = query.Distinct().OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ThenBy(e => e.FirstName); It didn't change anything. I added the output for you as well, so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that few employees have more than one location is causing the results to be repeated.You can handle it in multiple ways. Im using [Let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) clause to tackle the issue in the below example

```
public class Employee
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int PositionID { get; set; }

}


public class EmployeeLocation
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int PositionID { get; set; }
    public string Position1 { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}

public class JoinResult
{
    //Suggestion : Insetad of LocationID there should be a varibale that has all the locations of an employee
    public IEnumerable<int> LocationIDs;
    public int LocationID;
    public int EmployeeID;
    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;
    public string Position;
    public bool Active;
    
}

 //Setting up mock data
        List<Position> positions = new List<Position>();
        positions.Add(new Position() { Position1 = "Dentist", PositionID = 2 });
        positions.Add(new Position() { Position1 = "Dental Assistant", PositionID = 3 });
        positions.Add(new Position() { Position1 = "Administrative Assistant", PositionID = 4 });

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 4, FirstName = "Amanda", LastName = "Anderson (OH)", PositionID = 2 });
        employees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 25, FirstName = "Sally", LastName = "Stevens (OH)", PositionID = 3 });
        employees.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 30, FirstName = "Brenda", LastName = "Becon (OH)", PositionID = 4 });

        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        locations.Add(new Location() { LocationID = 4 });
        locations.Add(new Location() { LocationID = 5 });

        List<EmployeeLocation> employeeLocation = new List<EmployeeLocation>();
        employeeLocation.Add(new EmployeeLocation() { LocationID = 4, EmployeeID = 4 });
        employeeLocation.Add(new EmployeeLocation() { LocationID = 5, EmployeeID = 4 });
        employeeLocation.Add(new EmployeeLocation() { LocationID = 4, EmployeeID = 25 });
        employeeLocation.Add(new EmployeeLocation() { LocationID = 4, EmployeeID = 30 });
        employeeLocation.Add(new EmployeeLocation() { LocationID = 5, EmployeeID = 30 });


        var result = (from e in employees
                 join p in positions on e.PositionID equals p.PositionID
                 let employeeLocations = (from el in employeeLocation where el.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID select new { LocationID = el.LocationID })
                 where e.PositionID != 1 // Do not display the super administrator's data.
                 orderby e.LastName, e.FirstName
                 select new JoinResult
                 {
                     LocationID = employeeLocations.Select(p=>p.LocationID).First()//Here its just selecting the first location,
                     LocationIDs = employeeLocations.Select(p=> p.LocationID),//This is my suggestion
                     EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
                     LastName = e.LastName,
                     FirstName = e.FirstName,
                     Position = p.Position1,
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So here is the solution I came up with. I installed the morelinq NuGet package, which contains a DistinctBy() method. Then I added that method to the last line of the code shown in my problem.

```
JoinResultIList = JoinResultIQueryable
    .DistinctBy(jr => jr.EmployeeID)
    .ToList();
```